# React Native UI Component :How to implement a list view?

Tags: listview, user-interface, react-native, jsx

How to display the Image as circle shaped inside a card list.Now my  list view looks like this [image: profile]

But i want to list the text items to the right of this profile image.And my code in react is as below

**profile.js**

```
const Neighbour =({ neighbours }) =>{
    var { username,do_for_a_living,no_of_mutual_friends,profile_image_url} = neighbours;

    return (
      <Card>
      <CardSection>
      <View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
      <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />

      <Text>{username}</Text>
      <Text>{do_for_a_living}</Text>
      <Text>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
      <Button title="Friends" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
      </Button>
      </View>
      </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
};

    const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    thumbnail_style :{
        height: 50,
        width:50
    },
    thumbnailContainerStyle:{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight:10
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add border-radius for images and that'll be circular image and to align everything you should in a row you should `flexDirection` to `row`

```
       <Card>
   <CardSection>
  <View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
     <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />
     <View>
       <Text>{username}</Text>
       <Text>{do_for_a_living}</Text>
       <Text>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
     </View>
     <Button title="Friends" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
 </View>
 </CardSection>
</Card>
const styles= StyleSheet.create({
thumbnail_style :{
    height: 50,
    width:50,
    borderRadius:50 //add radius
},
thumbnailContainerStyle:{
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    marginLeft:10,
    marginRight:10,
    flexDirection:"row" //align in row
},
});
```

Comment: For image its working but when i given the property `flexDirection` every text come to the left in a single line.I want to list in a row one after other

Comment: oh ok! so u wanted to place inside a separate view that two texts only like this:`<View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
     <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />
     <View>
<Text>{username}</Text>
     <Text>{do_for_a_living}</Text>
     <Text>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
</View>
     <Button title="Friends" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
 </View>`
edit: `i'm updating the answer`

Answer (score 0):

To make a image circular you must add a **border-radius** style to the image and as you want to align all items to the left of the image so then add **flexDirection as row** on the wrapper div. Your code will be as follows:-

```
const Neighbour =({ neighbours }) =>{
    var { username,do_for_a_living,no_of_mutual_friends,profile_image_url} = neighbours;

    return (
      <Card>
      <CardSection>
      <View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
      <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />

      <Text>{username}</Text>
      <Text>{do_for_a_living}</Text>
      <Text>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
      <Button title="Friends" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
      </Button>
      </View>
      </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
};

    const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    thumbnail_style :{
        height: 50,
        width:50,
        borderRadius: 25
    },
    thumbnailContainerStyle:{
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight:10,
        flexDirection: row
    },
});
```

**UPDATE:-**

As you want only one item in a single row on the left of the image so you need to wrap the elements in the view as follows:-

```
const Neighbour =({ neighbours }) =>{
    var { username,do_for_a_living,no_of_mutual_friends,profile_image_url} = neighbours;

    return (
      <Card>
      <CardSection>
      <View style= {styles.thumbnailContainerStyle}>
        <Image style ={styles.thumbnail_style} source={{uri : profile_image_url}} />
        <View style={styles.thumbnailChildWrapper}>
          <Text>{username}</Text>
          <Text>{do_for_a_living}</Text>
          <Text>{no_of_mutual_friends} Mutual friends</Text>
          <Button title="Friends" onPress={() =>console.log("clicked")}>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
      </CardSection>

      </Card>
    );
};

    const styles= StyleSheet.create({
    thumbnail_style :{
        height: 50,
        width:50,
        borderRadius: 25  ==> add this to make image circular
    },
    thumbnailContainerStyle:{
        justifyContent: 'space-between', ==> add space-between so that there is space in text and image
        alignItems:'center',
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight:10,
        flexDirection: 'row'  ==> add row so that they come in single row
    },
    thumbnailChildWrapper:{
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```